# display a log file in real time with tkinter text field (python2.7)

Tags: python, tkinter, tail

I am trying to write a GUI that can display the log file in real time (tail -f log). The new line from the log file can be printed out into the terminal, but it cannot be loaded into the text field (line #). Can any one tell me why it won't put back to the text field?

```
from Tkinter import *
import os, time
import tkFileDialog

class Controller(object):
    def __init__(self, master):
        """ Main interface:
        master - the top level window
        """
        self._master = master

        frame1 = Frame(self._master)
        label = Label(self._master, text="Select a Log File")
        label.pack(side=TOP)
        currentLogfile = StringVar(self._master)
        LogfileList = [f for f in os.listdir('.') if os.path.isfile(f)]
        currentLogfile.set(LogfileList[0])
        chooseLog = OptionMenu(self._master, currentLogfile, *LogfileList, command = self.file_open)
        chooseLog.config(width = "300")
        chooseLog.pack(side=TOP)
        self._master.config(menu=chooseLog)
        self._Text=Text(frame1, bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
        self._Text.pack(side = TOP,fill=BOTH, expand = True,pady=20)
        w = Scrollbar(self._Text)
        w.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        frame1.pack(side=TOP, fill=BOTH, padx=5,expand=True)

    def file_open(self,filename):        
        #clear text field
        self._Text.delete('1.0', END)
        with open(filename,'r') as f:
            loglines = follow(f)
            for line in loglines:
                #print line
                self._Text.insert(END,line)

def follow(thefile):
    thefile.seek(0,2)
    while True:
        line = thefile.readline()
        if not line:
            time.sleep(5)
            continue
        yield line                


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root=Tk()
    c=Controller(root)
    root.title("log")
    root.geometry("750x500")
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Tkinter doesn't work well with `time.sleep` and with other loops (i.e. `while True`, etc) because it blocks its mainloop. You have want to have a look at the `after` method of any tkinter's widget. I can't help you more because I am not understanding exactly what you want to accomplish with the `follow` function..., if you explain it a little bit better.

Comment: You're probably going to need to use threads for this.  If this is all done in a single thread, most of the time is going to be spent in the `follow()` generator just waiting for input, and the gui will be completely unresponsive.

Comment: What I am trying to do is : writing a text dialog to display the log file while the log file keeps getting updated. Program A  keeps writing new line into the log file;and this widget show the log file in real time, as soon as (with 5 seconds delay) program A writes a new line, it display a new line in the text field. Thank you

Comment: I would do this with `after` but there is `readline` which blocks everything and `mainloop` can't do its job. There is non-blocking `readline` so you will have to use threads.

Comment: As long as you do a non-blocking `read()`, you can simply read what's there, then use `after` to read more in a few hundred milliseconds. You don't need threads.

Comment: I have created a simple terminal/console emulator (where you can for example type some bash commands, etc) using threads, you can [have a look at it](https://github.com/dossan/tkinter/blob/master/personal/widgets/Console.py) and try to do something similar to what I did.